# How can I pass an addtional value to a custom ModelState.IsValid method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

// In a partial class I am trying to create a custom ModelState.IsValid method. So far, it takes an `object` as a parameter and receives all the values of properties decorated with a validation attribute. This is great but I'd like to pass the method another parameter from the view. Then, I can use the additional value to help determine validity and possibly return a custom message based on the additional value.

Below is the partial class and some IsValid methods I've tried.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(CS_Parameter_Statewide_AllGrades_ScenarioMetaData))]
public partial class CS_Parameter_Statewide_AllGrades_Scenario
{   
    public int Category { get; set; }

    public class CS_Parameter_Statewide_AllGrades_ScenarioMetaData
    {
        [FormatAttribute] 
        public double Amount { get; set; }
    }

}

public class FormatAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable // IClientValidatable for client side Validation
{
    // this does not work; i don't know how to pass an additional value
    public override bool IsValid(object value, int additonalValue)
    {
        return true;
    }

    // this is what I would like to do
    public override string IsValid(object value, int additonalValue)
    {

        if (additonalValue == 1)
            // validation method 1
            // return message 1
        else if (additonalValue == 2)
            // validation method 2
            // return message 2
        else
            // validation method 3
            // return message 3
    }

    // this is something I was playing with
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {

        var message = "ohoh";
        return new ValidationResult(message);
    }

    // Implement IClientValidatable for client side Validation
    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        return new ModelClientValidationRule[] { new ModelClientValidationRule { ValidationType = "dropdown", ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessage } };
    }
}
```

`

Comment: `ValidationAttribute` does not have a method `string IsValid` You specify the message in the `ErrorMessage` property. Not clear what your doing here - where does `additonalValue` come from?

Comment: The `additonalValue` would come from the view. Then, I would format the `value` based on the `additionalValue`. I have a property (actually a few properties) that needs to be formatted based on the `additionalValue`.

Comment: How would I call and use the ValidationResult IsValid method?

Comment: If `additonalValue` is determined from a property in your model, then you need to have a constructor that accepts the name of the property so that you can then get its value and use it in you conditional statements.

Comment: Yes it is a property in the model. Do you think you could give me a small example? I'm not really sure what you're saying

Comment: I'll add an answer, but I'm not really sure from your question if its what you are after - I don't understand what mean by `// return formatted value`? A validation attribute is for validating a property  (meets a certain condition) but this seems to suggest that you want to reformat the value based on some condition (which is not what the attribute is for)

Comment: You're right that was incorrect. The type of validation will differ based on the `additional value`. Then, I also want to return different messages based on the  `additional value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a constructor to pass the name of a property whose value will contain the data use to compare and validate. For example

Model

```
[Format("MyOtherProperty")]
public double Amount { get; set; }

public int MyOtherProperty { get; set; } // the property use to validate
```

Attribute

```
public class FormatAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
  private readonly string _otherProperty;
  public FormatAttribute(string otherProperty)
  {
    _otherProperty = otherProperty;
  }

  protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
  {
    var property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_otherProperty);
    if (property == null)
    {
       return new ValidationResult(string.Format("Unknown property: {0}", _otherProperty));
    }
    object otherValue = property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
    if (otherValue == someValue) // cast otherValue to correct type
    {
      return new ValidationResult("some error message");
    }
    else if (....)
    {
      return new ValidationResult("another error message");
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Create Constructor and provide additional Field name in that constructor

```c#
public class FormatAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable // IClientValidatable for client side Validation
{
private string _additionalAttribute;
  public FormatAttribute(string additionalAttribut)
  {
    _additionalAttribute = additionalAttribut
  }
}
```

Then in IsValid function using ValidationContext you can retrieve the value of additional field

```
 protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        object additionalFieldValue = GetPropertyValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, _additionalField);
         // Do Logic Here
    }
```